# SQLPLUS 18c unable to connect to database 19c, get invalid password, but CAN connect through SQLDEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-connection, sqlplus

Using SQLPLUS 18c on windows 10pc, which has Oracle XE 18c
get invalid password response when try to connect to 19c EE on ODA

TNSPING reached the 19c database

Using same account and password from SQL developer on same PC,

I can connect to the 19c database on the server.

thanks

tried sqlplus uid/pwd@my19cdb

get invalid uid/pwd message

tried tnsping my19cdb  works

tried connecting through SQLDEVELOPER   and it works

Comment: one of 3 things are happening - you're connecting to the wrong database, you're password is wrong (they are case sensitive), or you're connecting as SYS and forgetting the 'as sysdba'

Comment: A common cause is you are trying to connect to the container root database not a pluggable database within that container.  Double check your service name in the tnsnames.ora file

Comment: Hi Thanx for your answers.  I was using a .batt file to connect from windows.  I had copied the id/password from the .bat into SQLDEVELOPER and it worked. There were special characters in the password, and in the .bat file, i didnt have them quoted properly. When I changed the password to have no special characters, and then no quotes, it works fine.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password in the .bat file I was using to initiate sqlplus had special characters and these were not quoted properly.  When i change the password to have no special characters, it worked fine. So Jeff had the right answer.

Comment: You can add comment & accept the correct answer